# What is using this network socket?

Tags: networking, process, freebsd, open-files

I'm trying to use NTP to update the time on my machine. However, it gives me an error:

```
host # ntpdate ntp1.example.org
10 Aug 12:38:50 ntpdate[7696]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting
```

What does the error "socket is in use" mean? How can I see what is using this socket?

This happens on my CentOS 4.x system, but I also see it on FreeBSD 7.x, Ubuntu 10.04 and Solaris 10.

Comment: In Stack Overflow: [What processes are using which ports on unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/126002/38108) (2008-09-24)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do

```
lsof -n | grep -i "TCP\|UDP" | grep -v "ESTABLISHED\|CLOSE_WAIT"
```

to see all of your listening ports, but dollars to donuts that ntpd is running:

```
service ntpd status
```

And as for "What does socket in use" mean? If I can be forgiven for smoothing over some wrinkles (and for the very basic explanation, apologies of most of this is remedial for you)...TCP/IP (the language of the internet) specifies that each computer has an IP address, which uniquely identifies that computer on the internet. In addition, there are 65,000 numbered ports on each IP address that can be connected to.

When you want to connect to a web server, you open the site in your browser, but the machinery underneath is actually connecting you to port 80 on the web server's IP. The web server's daemon (the program listening for connections to port 80) uses a "socket" to hold open that port, reserving it for itself. Only one program can use the same port at a time.

Since you had ntpd running, it was using that port. 'ntpdate' tried to access that port, but since it was already held open, you got the 'socket already in use' error.

**Edit**
Changed to account for UDP as well

Comment: lsof rocks my world!  grep on IPv4 as well to find various IP based things.

Comment: "apologies to everyone who already knew this" -- Don't apologize. One purpose of this site is to provide good answers to common questions. The purpose of this early beta is to provide content.

Comment: I know, but I wanted to make sure the person asking knew I wasn't trying to talk down to them.

Comment: I asked the question, and you weren't talking down to me. I also know the answer, but I figure it's a good question for the beta. And your answer was much better then anything I would write ;)

Comment: @MattSimmons there is no `Isof` command in my CentOS 7.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use netstat to look for open sockets--it's much cleaner than using lsof as the other posters have suggested. Try this command line as root

`netstat -lp -u -t`

to view all listening connections, including their associated pid's and programs. The -l parameter is what specifies listening connections, -p specifies that you want to see the PID/name and -t and -u tell netstat that you want only TCP and UDP connections (IPv4 and IPv6).

If you want to see numeric port and host names (ie. not resolved in the case of hosts, and not transformed to service names in the case of ports), you can add `-n` to the command line above.

**EDIT:** This works on Linux--I don't know how well it works on BSD, as I don't have any BSD-based boxes around.

Comment: +1 : This is the only answer which actually shows the ntpd process (which listens on UDP by default).

Comment: For the humans: Your flags are equivalent to `netstat --listen --programs --udp --tcp`

Comment: FreeBSD does not support the '-p' ("Show Programs"), which is why people use LSOF. It also does not support the -l ("Show Listening Sockets") flags, but I think you can do that with `| grep LISTEN`, but that excludes the UDP connections. But otherwise, I think the equivalent flags on FreeBSD are: `netstat -p udp -p tcp -a`, but `netstat -a` might be simpler.

Comment: @Stefan: My answer will show UDP sockets as well.

Comment: @kbyrd : Interesting. It doesn't show UDP packets for me. See my comment to your post.

Comment: @Stefan: That seems so...backwards. :-/ (Re: BSD netstat not supporting -p or -l)

Comment: @B : I agree. But I think the original BSD `netstat` didn't support the flags, therefore the current netstat doesn't introduce that change either. It's very *BSD!

Answer (score 2):

On FreeBSD, you can also use sockstat in case lsof doesn't work for you (e.g. on virtualized systems that don't have /dev/mem for whatever reason).  To get a list of all programs with listening IPv4 sockets:

```
sockstat -l4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lsof` to find which application is using this socket.

Answer (score 1):

As root, do this:

```
lsof | grep IPv4 | grep LISTEN
```

This will show you all processes that are listening on IPv4 sockets. You may want to add `-b` to prevent `lsof` from doing some things that might block it. If you do that you'll probably also want to redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`.

Comment: For me, this doesn't seem to show udp packets. I'm testing on an Ubuntu box which is running rsyslogd, listening on port 514/udp.

Comment: I need to do `sudo lsof |grep UDP` to see UDP packets.

Answer (score 0):

Toying with this three-in-one on OS X 10.9.5:

`sudo lsof | grep \ IPv | sort ; clear ; sudo lsof -U ; clear ; sudo netstat -a`

Answer (score 0):

With FreeBSD use the `-u` switch so that `ntpdate` uses an unprivileged port instead.

Like: `ntpdate -v -b -u 0.freebsd.pool.ntp.org`

Use `man ntpdate` to see what `-v` and `-b` does.

Comment: The ntpdate on Debian has the `-u` option, since it's from ntp.org, I imagine most systems have it.